# Android show picture in browser over WIFI and local network, how?

Tags: android

I am using a serversocket in android. I connect in a browser to: `192.168.1.100:8080`.

I am trying to show a picture in my PC's browser, from my android assets, my code is:

```
String js=openFileFromAssets("js");                         
send("<head>" +
"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" " +
"href=\"file:///android_asset/css.css\" />" +
"<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" value=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2\">Második oldal " +
"<img src='file:///android_asset/icon.png'><div id='asd' style='clear:left'>0</div> " + 
js + 
"</head>");
```

How can I show that picture from the `assets` folder, to my browser? (icon.png)
I have the `/assets` folder.

Thanks, Leslie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to bother writing your own (unless you really want to write your own, in which case you'll need much more than what you have). Take a look at one of the existing chunks of code such as [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Tiny-Application/HttpServer.htm), and then modify the output to stream the content out of the asset folder using [AssetManager.open](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: ok, and how to link it in my string: <img src='file:///android_asset/icon.png'> this is good? or: 192.168.1.101:8080/icon.png? or something else?

Comment: You'd probably want to use a relative URI (so something like `<img src="/icon.png" />` and then translate that in your server to serve up the contents of the specific asset. The `file:///` URLs will only work in a WebView loaded from within your app on the phone, not in the generic Android browser or on a different computer.

Comment: changed to: getLocalIpAddress() and it works very good, thanks